# Putting methods on Object.getPrototypeOf(this)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

See this class definition:

```
function MyClass (property) {
    // Private
    var privateVariable;
    var privateMethod = function () {};

    // Public
    this.publicProperty = property;
    this.publicPrivilegedMethodOnInstance = function () {};
    Object.getPrototypeOf(this).publicPrivilegedMethodOnPrototype = function () {};
}
MyClass.prototype.publicMethod = function () {};

var myMyClass = new MyClass('foo');
```

The method `publicPrivilegedMethodOnPrototype` is public, yet can access private variables (which `publicMethod`) can’t. It’s also shared on the prototype, which `publicPrivilegedMethodOnInstance` is not.

Any downsides of defining `publicPrivilegedMethodOnPrototype` like this? I guess ECMAScript 5 is a requirement, and that the method is redefined every time MyClass is instantiated.

Comment: `publicPrivilegedMethodOnPrototype` can access private variables due to **closures**.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yeah, that’s the idea. `publicMethod` can’t do that since it’s outside the MyClass function definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a very bad idea.

So you create many objects but as you're assigning the property to the prototype of all of them, at some point even functions which weren't meant to access certain values will do it... **This is very odd**.

A given prototype function is meant to access properties from the object whose own the prototype using `this`:

```
function X() {
   this.text = "hello world";
}
X.prototype.doStuff() {
   console.log(this.text);
};
```

Thus, avoid that anti-pattern. It makes no sense. My advise is that you need to deal with the absense of access modifiers in JavaScript instead of blindly looking for a workaround.

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate on _“even functions which weren't meant to access certain values will do it”_? Because isn’t `MyClass.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(this)`, i.e. the methods are placed on the same “level”? But `publicPrivilegedMethodOnPrototype` has access to the private variables due to closures.

Comment: @TomSöderlund Yeah, and this is the problem with your idea. Do you imagine more than an object created from the same constructor function accessing last constructor function call's captured variables? :\